# Change behavior when a tab in TabLayout is selected

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, toast, android-tablayout

I have a basic TabLayout that has 2 lists under 2 tabs (1 list in tab A and 1 list in tab B) setup with a ViewPager something like below.

```
// CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
CustomPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
adapter.addFragments();
TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
viewPager.setAdapter(PagerAdapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

The given situation is that a user is seeing the tab A on screen. At this point, when a user taps on the tab B, I want the app to make a toast message saying it's not possible to view tab B, instead of actually navigating to the tab B.

In other words, I don't want the app to navigate to tab B, I just want it to show a Toast message while staying on tab A when the user taps on tab B.

I tried something like
`((LinearLayout) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).setEnabled(false);` but this didn't work because the tab is disabled by the code above so it doesn't even show the Toast message because it doesn't sense the click event.

I feel like I need to keep it enabled (by setEnabled(true) or something) and somehow override the method so the app show a Toast message instead of navigating to another tab.

How can I achieve this? I couldn't find any other stackoverflow post related to this issue..

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code to enable/disable any tab in tablayout:

```
LinearLayout tabStrip = ((LinearLayout)tabLayout.getChildAt(0));
            tabStrip.getChildAt(1).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                     if(your condition) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Tab Enable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                    } else {                   
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Tab Disable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                     }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to tweak it a bit but still very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a Listener to tablayout as bellow

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tab.select();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "This is toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: this doesn't fix the issue because they get called after tab b is already open

Comment: Yeah.. it will only work in such a way that you will get back to first tab only after second is open.